# Change map color on specific provinces

Tags: javascript, highcharts, colors

I'm using the demo linked [here](https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/mapdata/countries/it/it-all).

```
// Prepare demo data
// Data is joined to map using value of 'hc-key' property by default.
// See API docs for 'joinBy' for more info on linking data and map.
var data = [
    ['it-na', 0],
    ['it-tp', 1],
    ['it-pa', 2],
    ['it-me', 3],
    ...
    ['it-pn', 107],
    ['it-vi', 108],
    ['it-tv', 109]
];

// Create the chart
Highcharts.mapChart('container', {
    chart: {
        map: 'countries/it/it-all'
    },

title: {
    text: 'Highmaps basic demo'
},

subtitle: {
    text: 'Source map: <a href="http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/it/it-all.js">Italy</a>'
},

mapNavigation: {
    enabled: true,
    buttonOptions: {
        verticalAlign: 'bottom'
    }
},

colorAxis: {
    min: 0
},

series: [{
    data: data,
    name: 'Random data',
    states: {
        hover: {
            color: '#BADA55'
        }
    },
    dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        format: '{point.name}'
    }
}]
});
```

This is the demo code but I would like to change the color used only for specific provinces. Actually all the provinces are blue but I want to change color according to the regions.

Answer (score 0):

i also tried to do that:

```
    Highcharts.mapChart('container', {
    chart: {
        map: 'countries/it/it-all'
    },

    title: {
        text: 'Highmaps basic demo'
    },

    subtitle: {
        text: 'Source map: <a href="http://code.highcharts.com/mapdata/countries/it/it-all.js">Italy</a>'
    },

    mapNavigation: {
        enabled: true,
        buttonOptions: {
            verticalAlign: 'bottom'
        }
    },

    colorAxis: {
        min: 0
    },

    series: [
            {
        name: 'Prodotti Acquistati Area1',
        states: {
            hover: {
                color: '#BADA55'
            }
        },
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            format: '{point.name}'
        },
        data: [
    ['it-na', 0],
    ['it-tp', 1],
    ['it-pa', 2]
                            ] 
             },
         {
        name: 'Prodotti Acquistati Area2',
        states: {
            hover: {
                color: '#BADA55'
            }
        },
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            format: '{point.name}'
        },
        data: [
    ['it-rm', 52],
    ['it-ch', 53],
    ['it-vt', 54]
                            ]
                }
        ]
});
```

but it only load the second series....

Comment: hi i have a new problem ..
if I pass to the map of Italy a series of values, it is colored according to a scale of nuances that I have defined.
if I click on a button in which I update the series, the data is updated but the color scale always remains the first one loaded. I tried to use Mapchart.reload () or mapchart.redraw () but nothing works ... how can I force the map update?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by adding color to the particular data points and setting `keys` property to specify which option maps to which key in the data point array. Check the demo and code posted below.

**Code:**

```
var data = [
  ['it-na', 0, 'red'],
  ['it-tp', 1, 'green']
]

chart: {
  series: [{
        data: data,
    keys: ['hc-key', 'value', 'color']
  }]
}
```

**Demo:**

- https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pkm6narj/

**API reference:**

- https://api.highcharts.com/highmaps/series.map.keys

Comment: thanks for the reply, but in this way I lose the color gradation ... I would like to keep the possibility of selecting the color shade and in addition being able to choose which color...is it possible?

Comment: You can use `colorAxis.stops`: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/colorAxis.stops. Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/1f0rsgey/

Comment: now it works but for some reason  the context button title do not appear when mouse is over....any idea?

Comment: What is the context button title?

Comment: the menu in the upper right corner where you can download the chart in the various formats. when you pass the mouse over it appears a title that does not appear to me anymore ... and I don't understand why

Comment: Could you reproduce it in the jsfiddle?

Comment: I don't know why but it doesn't work I can't pass it on jsfiddle